# OpenCV for image detection and analyzing in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, opencv

I want to use opencv in iOS app. I cloned openCV through terminal (git clone https://github.com/opencv/opencv.git) for building `opencvframework`.

I used this command `python opencv/platforms/ios/build_framework.py ios` as per official opencv website's tutorial but i get an error that say

> ERROR: Command '['xcodebuild', '-version']' returned non-zero exit
>   status 1

I think that might be opencv compatitibility error. I am using Xcode 8.2.1 in MAC OSX El capitan. Can somebody tell me what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

There is a same issue on Github, and it looks has been fixed:
https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/6093

Please check:

> If I add "#include " in gzguts.h, this error can be fixed.

And I have successfully build the framework under maxOS Sierra 10.12.6 and Xcode 8.3.3:[image]

You could download it directly from link: http://onqouewnn.bkt.clouddn.com/opencv2.framework.zip